# recovering original photos after they are photoshopped

Tags: photoshop

I Photoshop photos and can't figure out how to recover originals after saving them. !I've tried Photoshop and blurr3 and my phone's edit photos but doesn't work and I forgot what app I used to distort them. They are very distorted to the point I can't make out anything at all.

Comment: Did you use copies, did you use layers, did you make backups?

Comment: Could you clarify if you actually used Photoshop, the application from Adobe, or if you're using "Photoshop" as a generic term to mean "editing photos in any app"?

Comment: Can you post an example of a "distorted" image, and describe exactly what you did?

Answer (score 1):

If you edited and saved over the originals then there is nothing you can do. The only possibility I can see is to check on your memory card to see if the originals are still on there, as some phone apps will save the changes (edits) as new files.